# How can I close a hamburger menu after an anchor is clicked

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, divi

I am sorry if this question has been asked a thousand times but I am not a coder more a designer. I am developing a one page site for my business with a hamburger menu that opens to cover the page. I have anchor links to the different sections. I got the code from different tutorials online but have one problem. How do I get the menu to close when the user clicks on the anchor link? I know there is a bit of JS code that I need to add but I can't figure out how.
I am using Wordpress with the DIVI theme.

This is the code that I have added to my slide in menu.

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $('#slide-in-open').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('open');
    $('.slide-in-menu-container').toggleClass('slide-in-menu');
  });
});
```

```css
#slide-in-open {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.line {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  height: 4px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #EA5B13;
  border-radius: 9px;
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: .2s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: .2s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: .2s ease-in-out;
  transition: .2s ease-in-out;
}

.line-2 {
  background: #96315c;
  top: 10px;
}

.line-3 {
  background: #65186A;
  top: 20px;
}

#slide-in-open.open .line-1 {
  top: 10px;
  background: #EA5B13;
  right: 40%;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
}

#slide-in-open.open .line-2 {
  top: 10px;
  background: #96315c;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
}

#slide-in-open.open .line-3 {
  top: 10px;
  background: #65186A;
  left: 40%;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
}

.slide-in-menu {
  right: 0 !important;
  opacity: 1 !important;
}

.slide-in-menu-container {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.05s ease !important;
  -moz-transition: all 0.05s ease !important;
  -o-transition: all 0.05s ease !important;
  -ms-transition: all 0.05s ease !important;
  transition: all 0.05s ease !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I made a snippet for you. Please add your HTML as well so as to make a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

`$(el).click(function(){...})` is deprecated

use `$(el).on('click', function(){...})` instead

source: [api.jquery.com/click-shorthand/](https://api.jquery.com/click-shorthand/)

otherwise, it should work.
unless there is an issue with the html markup, but you haven't posted any html so we can't know.

Answer (score -1):

You can use this code:

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $('#slide-in-open').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('open');
    $('.slide-in-menu-container').toggleClass('slide-in-menu');
  });
  // For the anchor link
  $('ul.menu li a').click(function() {
    $('#slide-in-open').removeClass('open');
    $('.slide-in-menu-container').removeClass('slide-in-menu');
  });
});
```

[image: Screen grab of the inspector]

Comment: Hi Sofiqul, thanks for your reply. I added your code but didn't seen to work. Do you think its something to do with the 'ul.menu li a' in the code ?

Comment: @Paul808Images Yes, you have to change the anchor selector like your website structure. If you can show me a screenshot of your HTML element I can show you the selector.

Comment: Also, you can share your website URL if it's live.

Comment: The site is not live and I don't know how to show you the html element. As I'm using DIVI, it hides all that. Could I use the inspection tools in firefox?

Comment: Yes, just use the inspection tool and select the anchor link.

Comment: I have added the screen shot to your answer, just waiting for admin approval

Comment: Let me check when it's approved.

Comment: User this script:

jQuery(function($) {
  $('#slide-in-open').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('open');
    $('.slide-in-menu-container').toggleClass('slide-in-menu');
  });
  // For the anchor link
  $('ul.dsm-menu li a').click(function() {
    $('#slide-in-open').removeClass('open');
    $('.slide-in-menu-container').removeClass('slide-in-menu');
  });
});

I hope it will work.

Comment: Thanks Sofiqul, I'll check that out and tell you how it went